# nginx is getting "Resource temporarily unavailable" on boot up only

Tags: nginx, flask, uwsgi, newrelic, alpine-linux

I have a `flask` service for external and internal usages.

Recently, in the last month, when deploying to `production` internal only, one endpoint is timing out and the `nginx` is reporting `Resource temporarily unavailable`.

it **returns to normal after a few restarts**. When trying to investigate:

- I didn't see any increase in the number of requests during the last month
- I have new relic installed but I don't see anything out of the ordinary (suggestions are welcomed)

full error message is :

`2018/01/04 17:46:23 [error] 19#19: *259 connect() to unix:/run/server.socket failed (11: Resource temporarily unavailable) while connecting to upstream, client: 10.0.1.181, server: , request: "POST /mobile_push_data HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://unix:/run/server.socket:", host: "mobile.production.my_domain.com"`

the service is running in a docker file running on `alpine:3.6`